# Storing data securely in javascript (autosuggestions)

Tags: javascript, php, security, autosuggest

How can I store data on the clients side securely (not viewable/visible) in javascript.

In particular, I want to grab an array from the database with PHP and then use that array for autosuggestion data. Currently I am setting the array as a JS variable, however it can be seen in the html page source code.

I have looked at autosuggestions online and came across: http://www.brandspankingnew.net/specials/ajax_autosuggest/ajax_autosuggest_autocomplete.html

I cannot find where the autosuggestion data is being stored, which is what I want for my script. Help!

Comment: don't do it on client-side (JavaScript)

Comment: Using an addon on like FireBug I can easily see what are the autosuggestions sent by server @ http://www.brandspankingnew.net/specials/ajax_autosuggest/ajax_autosuggest_autocomplete.html.

Comment: Why not do it client side? It would reduce pressure on the server by not requesting the database every keypress...

Comment: @Cybernate, I set my browser to work offline and the suggestions still work, so they are being stored somewhere in the browser but where?

Comment: Nevermind, I see the ajax get requests are being made

Comment: @John: That has to be because you have used it multiples times and the data is already stored in a JS variable. Try a character combination that you haven't tried before. If you use firebug NET panel as Cybernate suggests you will see the calls to the server as GET requests and responses.

Answer (score 2):

No,  what you are trying to do is impossible.  Javascript is being run by the client and thus the client has absolute control over the data.   If you are trying to store a secret in javascript then an attacker can use a [debugger](http://www.ollydbg.de/) to see it in memory.   But this is the worst case.  Its easier a lot easier to manipulate the traffic with TamperData,  or manipulate the javascript directly with Greasemonkey.

Answer (score 0):

If it is sensitive data like usernames or passwords, you shouldn't auto suggest anything. If it is not sensitive data, the AJAX solution from your link is the obvious way to go, but you could easily store it in a cookie if it is not more than 4kb, or in various cookies otherwise.